# Aligning image caption area with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a component in Angular that shows a collection of products as images in a four-column grid.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products track by $index" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
<div class="col-sm-3 title-box-sm" ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1, $index + 2, $index + 3]" ng-if="products[i] != null" ng-class="{hover: hover}" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
    <a href="{{ products[i].url }}">
        <img alt="{{ products[i].alt }}" ng-src="{{ products[i].image_url }}"/>
        <div class="image-caption">
            {{ products[i].name }}
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the ability to hover over an image and have it pop out, showing beneath it a caption area that shows additional informtion.  The popping-out works fine, but the caption below it does not line up.  It seems to do with the fact that its position is absolute.  These are the relevant style rules being applied for this effect are

```
.title-box-sm.hover {
-moz-transform: scale(1.03);
-o-transform: scale(1.03);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
transform: scale(1.03);
z-index: 600;
```

}

```
.title-box-sm.hover .image-caption {
display: block;
position: absolute;
background: white;
width: 100%;
line-height: 3.4em;
```

}

but it does not line up correctly on the right, and any padding added to image-caption further pushes it out.  It needs to be an absolute position so that when hovered-over it doesn't push everything else down.  How can I get the caption to always align to the left and right of the image, no matter how I style the image-caption container?  Sorry if this has already been answered, I could not find the relevant article.

Comment: Please post a working code snippets that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because your CSS is set to make the caption 100% width, and not the actual image width. I stripped out the angular stuff as it is not relevant and created a quick fiddle to show what I think you're after.

Fixed Width: https://jsfiddle.net/w3nc95dg/
Fluid width: https://jsfiddle.net/w3nc95dg/4/

CSS changes I made:

```
.title-box-sm:hover {
-moz-transform: scale(1.03);
-o-transform: scale(1.03);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
transform: scale(1.03);
z-index: 600;
}

.title-box-sm .image-caption {
display: none;
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
background: #66ffff;
/*width: 100px;*/
left: 15px;
right: 15px;
line-height: 3.4em;
}

.title-box-sm:hover .image-caption {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: The image width can vary depending on viewport size, so I can't just set a static width for the caption...it will also need to be the width of the image.

Comment: You can specify left and right and no width to keep the caption the same width as the column.  Default margins are 15px for bootstrap, so you have to take that into account. I updated the code above with relevant change.

https://jsfiddle.net/w3nc95dg/4/